# Google Apps Services - calendar event getId returns the id of the recurring event instead of the event id

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I am able to get all my events by doing the following:

```
function myFunction() {
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(id);
  var events = cal.getEvents(startTime, endTime);
  for ( var i in events ) {
    var id = events[i].getId();
  }
}
```

The issue is that all events that are part of a recurring event have the same id. How can I get the instanceId of my events?

I am using google apps script

How can I solve that?

Thanks

Comment: See this post, it is a solution. I use it but instead of comparing the title I compare on ID. Works great although a bit slow... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36116491/how-to-modify-a-specific-instance-of-an-event-series

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you going to do with the ids retrieved? You cannot retrieve recurring event `instanceId` using google-apps script alone.

You can try to use the [Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/instances#request) itself to make a GET http requests

```
https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/calendarId/events/eventId/instances
```

You will just need to use your `calendarId` and the recurring `eventId`. This is will give a JSON response with [event representations](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource-representations) which probably contains id that you need.

Comment: I was looking to use google-apps script alone. Thank you